# React with redux - alter response and then push to the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, response, axios, xor

I have an app where I download list of files, so I dispatch an action (using axios):

```
export function getFileList(foo, bar) {
  return {
    type: GET_FILE_LIST,
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: myApiUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I get something like this in return:

```
{
  "output":
    [
      {"file":"file15166.jpg","id":1234},
      {"file":"file231321.jpg","id":6432}
      (...)
    ], 
    "foo": "bar", 
    "etc": "etc"
}
```

Once I got the data I push it to the store:

```
case GET_FILE_LIST:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    files: action.payload.data.output
})
```

Now, my question is - what if I need to push also only IDs of these files to my redux store?

I mean in addition to `state.myReducer.files` I need also `state.myReducer.fileIds: [1234, 6432]`. How can I take a response, change it and then push to reducer?

I was thinking about running a loop on the response but doing it might cause side effects and these are forbidden in reducers, am I right? What's the right approach here? Excluding modifying the API's back-end of course.

I know the best place to do such stuff is in action, but I don't have response there yet :/ Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean _I don't have response there yet_?

Comment: If I understand Redux correctly - action just runs async action then the data is available as payload in reducer, thus I can't access it in the action and even if I would - I don't know how to push it to the reducer in both (original and modified) forms :(

Comment: have a look at: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect this might help you.

Comment: i guess your  `GET_FILE_LIST` action is only dispatched when you get data from API, so i think there is no problem in looping through the output and get the fileIds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case GET_FILE_LIST:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    files: action.payload.data.output
fileIds: action.payload.data.output.map(item=> item.id);
})
```

If you do it in this way, I don't see any reason why there should be any side effects.